# Nuxt3 + Vue3 - Saving file broke the application sometimes while HMR

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, vite, nuxt3

I have serious problem with the HMR of my Nuxt3 application:

While compiling the application for dev / production all things working well.
but if i trying to change some file in my application in `dev` mode there is strange errors appeard that broke the application.

after rerun `npm run dev` the error dissapeard.

Example for error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: items is not iterable
```

This error is not belongs to the application itself, it come from vuetify component.

or even error from my own composeable, something like `filters is not defined` although the variable is defined and return from the composable itself, and again, the problem is solved without change anything in the composable, i just need to try save the file again & again until the problem is solved.

Sometimes the error is related to the application itself, but there is no problem in the code, its seems like error in the vue compiler while HMR and its explain why after rerun the application the problem solved.

i tried to look for solution but not found anything in google or here.
the problem not appeared in my Nuxt2 applications.

I very confident that the problem related to the Vue compiler with the composition API, even if i put empty comment in my code and save the file, the app is broken.

There is anyone with any clue about this problem? thanks.